# Maven: Prevent inheritance of maven-release plugin configuration from parent pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm working with a Maven project that utilises the `maven-release-plugin`.

The pom has a parent project defined, which is shared across multiple projects, and includes `maven-release-plugin` in its pluginManagement, with some configuration set (including `tagNameFormat`).

I have an issue whereby the project is inheriting the configuration from the parent, which in-turn is incorrectly overriding the project (child)'s `maven-release-plugin` configuration for `tagNameFormat`.

I can see in the effective pom that it is inheriting the configuration from the parent *after* the project's configuration.  The result is that maven releases the project with an scm tag that is in the format set in the parent.

Is there a way (that I can't already find from searching) that would allow me to not amend the parent, whilst allowing the 'child' (project in context) to be build using **only** its own `tagNameFormat` ?

(the `tagNameFormat` in this case is in a different format to the project name)

I did experiment with `combine.self="override"` in the configuration tag, but to no avail.

Comment: Is the parent configuration in a `pluginManagement` section?

Comment: Could you add a (shortened) version of the POM, Parent POM and the effective POM?

Comment: @SteveC - yes.  It is a shared module so I am unlikely to be able to change that

Comment: And did you solve this in the end?